# Jumping problems. (new coder please be nice)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial about the basics of making games in Unity. Link to person :https://www.tiktok.com/@individualkex. I came across an issue, when I put the code for jumping in, and I ran the program, then tried to jump, (as you could guess) it did not work. This problem is probably very obvious, so sorry for my inexperience, here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject groundCheck;
    public float moveSpeed = 9.2f;
    public float acceleration = 50f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 10f;
    

    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    float moveX;
    int moveDir;
    bool grounded;

    void Awake() {
      rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update() {
      moveDir = (int)Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
      if(moveDir != 0)
          moveX = Mathf.MoveTowards(moveX, moveDir * moveSpeed, Time.deltaTime * acceleration);
      else
          moveX = Mathf.MoveTowards(moveX, moveDir * moveSpeed, Time.deltaTime * acceleration * 2f);

      grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.transform.position, .2f, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"));
      if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
          Jump();
    }

    void Jump() {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed, 0);
    }

   
  void FixedUpdate() {
    if (rigidBody.velocity.y < .75f * jumpSpeed || !Input.GetButton("Jump"))
         rigidBody.velocity += Vector3.up * Physics.gravity.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 5f;
    
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(moveX, rigidBody.velocity.y, 0);
  }
}
```

I don't know if this could be a problem with Unity itself, or something related to that, but I just need to get unstuck.
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'it did not work'.  What happened?

Comment: Please learn the basics before jumping onto a big project with no proper guidance

Comment: I'd check the values of `grounded` and `Input.GetButtonDown`, to see if they're actually set to true under desired condition. It's a basic debug trick yet very effective - never easily trust anything is working as planned. Also the gravity part seems weird - Rigidbody has a gravity property iirc. Some SO posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350411/unity-2d-jumping-script) indicates that you should use `AddForce` instead of changing velocity. Haven't been using unity for a few years, but I do remember I always wanted to avoid directly changing object velocity.

Comment: Is this worked ? ` Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") `

Answer (score 2):

The only code that would restrict you from jumping is this:

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
      Jump();
```

Your Jump(); seems to be fine and grounded seems to be fine as well. It seems like it may be a unity editor issue. Make sure you have set your ground to a "Ground" layer. If there is no "Ground" you can't jump.

Comment: Thank you. sorry for not knowing basically anything guys. Will learn more before asking again.

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere! I encountered this issue a number of times! I highly recommend the brackeys tutorials when it comes to unity on youtube also :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god guys, I'm so stupid.
I thought, (for SOME reason) that in order to jump, I had to press the top arrow key. I actually had to press the space bar.

Comment: It should be a comment.