# Cannot get rb.velocity to work when making a jumping script in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use rb.velocity in unity to make my 2D character jump. I have used Debug.Log() to check if unity registers the input, and it does. But it does not affect my character in game when pressing the button. Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 7f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Space was pressed");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried replacing the values with all sorts of things in the Vector2, but to no avail.

Comment: Could you share how your game object's rigidbody is set ? Also just for testing, set your jumpforce to a very large number to see if your character flies off the screen. Other thing is your `rb.MovePosition` line is also modifying your character's velocity.y and you don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

If your rigidbody is using gravity then in this case a small vertical velocity of `7f` would be negated by gravity very quickly (less than a second). You can check this in the physics settings of your project or with [`Rigidbody.useGravity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html).
If you intend to use gravity then it is recommended to use [`Rigidbody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to add an upward force to the object and let gravity bring it back down - example SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350411/unity-2d-jumping-script?rq=1).

If you want to turn off gravity and not use `AddForce` then it would be best to either use `Rigidbody.MovePosition` or set `Rigidbody.velocity`, but not both.

For example:

```
void Update() {
    movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, movement.y);
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        movement.y = jumpForce;
    }
    rb.velocity = movement;
}
```

But in that case you would have to manually figure out when the jump is complete and set a downwards velocity to bring it back to the ground yourself. If you want the easiest and most natural solution, then leveraging Unity's built-in physics with gravity and forces would be best.

Comment: Could you restate that first sentence, because as it stands, it sounds completely wrong. A velocity is instantly overwritten by gravity?

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec you're right, it wouldn't be _instantly_ overwritten. But in this case if the upward velocity is +7 m/s and acceleration is -9.81 m/s^2 (gravity), then the velocity would be canceled out in less than a second. I'll revise to make that more clear.

Comment: I have tried doing what you said, and implementing Rigidbody.AddForce. It still does not work though. I tried implementing the code in a new project to see if it was the project that was the problem, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm AddForce is very common way to implement jumping and there's plenty of tutorials out there. Maybe something like [this](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/) could help, sorry I can't be more help but there might be something going on that's external to your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your code looks fine. I would move the Input.GetKeyDown check into Update instead of FixedUpdate. But other than that it looks good.

Instead, make sure your `jumpForce` is not `0`. Just because you set the initial value in your script

```
public float jumpForce = 7f;
```

Doesn't mean that it is 7f. Check the script in the inspector and make sure it's not `0`. Setting values on scripts like you did only sets the initial value. If you created the jump force variable before assigning 7 to it, it will still be 0. You have to set the variables in the inspector.

And if that doesn't work use:

```
rb.AddForce(jumpForce * Vector3.up, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Instead of trying to manually set the velocity.